# PHP show message based on user had attach file or not attach file

Tags: php, html

Let's say I have this form:

```
<html>
<head></head>

<body>
<form action="add.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
File 1: <input type="file" name="file1" />
File 2: <input type="file" name="file2" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="ADD">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click submit button:
(1) If user didn't attach 2 files, show "2 files empty" message.
(2) If user attach file in file 1 or file 2, show "have 1 file" message.

I tried like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && ($_POST['submit'] == 'ADD'))
{
    if(!empty($_FILES['file1']) && !empty($_FILES['file2']))
    {
        echo '2 files empty';
    } 
    else
    {
        echo 'have 1 file';
    }
}
```

But I always get "2 files empty" when I attach file.
What am I writing wrong? How should I modify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the following a try:

```
if( !empty( $_FILES['file1']['name'] ) && !empty( $_FILES['file2']['name'] ) )
```

Add the `['name']` part so you compare a string.

Comment: @KKLMichael If this was the answer then please mark as such. This way other people will know the answer aswell

Answer (score 0):

if you arrive on the page for the first time by simply calling the URL you will have `array(0) { }` as the result for `var_dump($_FILES)`.
When you post your form **without** selecting a file this would result in

```
array(2) {
  ["file1"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["type"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["error"]=>
    int(4)
    ["size"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  ["file2"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["type"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["error"]=>
    int(4)
    ["size"]=>
    int(0)
  }
}
```

Checking for `empty($_FILES)` will give you a `false` now, because there is something in the array.
Instead of this, just check for the **name** or **tmp_name** of the $_FILES array contents like so

```
 if($_FILES['file1']['name']=='' && $_FILES['file2']['name']=='')
    {
        echo '2 files empty';
    } 
    else
    {
        echo 'have 1 file';
    }
```

Hope that helps
Alex